# On Mac OS X 10.5 where does the mysql database files reside

Tags: mysql, osx-leopard

I need to access the old files from MySQL that I backuped in an image disk.
Where can I find them? what files and extensions I should be looking for?
I'm using 10.5.8
Thanks in advance

Comment: More important than knowing the OS version is knowing how you installed MySQL. Different package managers install the software to different folders. Also, this question may be better suited for [SuperUser SE](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

On mac OX 10.8

This is where it is

```
/usr/local/mysql
```

and inside data folder

The easy way to get here is GO > Go to folder > just type the location